# Remove SplitContainer panel padding in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, padding, splitcontainer

Is there a way to remove to padding from the `Panel` within a `SplitContainer`? So far I tried setting or overwriting the Padding Property with no effort. I don't necessarily want to end up custom drawing everything either.

[Screenshot http://xload.dev-ch.com/6ef9241aba201922/screen397.jpg](http://xload.dev-ch.com/6ef9241aba201922/screen397.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the padding issue and some code of what you have tried?

Comment: It apparently seems to be the TabPage, which causes the padding. Sorry for misleading you. Here is a screenshot: http://xload.dev-ch.com/6ef9241aba201922/screen397.jpg

Comment: What control have you got inside the TabControl? Is it a RichTextBox? and which padding you want to remove?

Comment: In this example, it is a `TextBox`, but you can see it on any control. I want the `TextBox` when rendered without border to entirely fit the TabPage without any margins to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `TextBox` to fill the entire `TabPage` control, you need to set the `TextBox` `Dock` property to `Fill`, change the `Margin` property to `0,0,0,0` and then in the `TabPage` properties, make sure the `Padding` is set to `0,0,0,0`.

Comment: I have the docked `TextBox` and set its margin to 0 as well as the margin of the `TabPage`. It still does not work.